# How much server spec for seed nodes?

Tags: nodeos, build, memory

I will build `nodeos v1.7.x` (not bp) for follows:

- send transaction transfer tokens (withdrawal)
- monitoring action trace (deposit)

so I will used `state_history_plugin` with `fill-postgresql`

My custom configure:

```
chain-state-db-size-mb= 24576
read-mode = head
validation-mode = light
p2p-peer-address = *****
...

plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::state_history_plugin
plugin = eosio::db_size_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin
```

run command:

```
$ nodeos --chain-threads=32 --disable-replay-opts --trace-history
```

I think **nodeos** consumed state db size (used bytes key):

```
curl --request POST --url https://public.eosinfra.io/v1/db_size/get

{
  "free_bytes": "18635175776",
  "used_bytes": "7134627984",
  "size": "25769803760",
  ...
}
```

My Server specs:

- CPU: 32 core
- MEM: 32 GBytes
- HDD: 3TB SAS (no SSD)

Questions:

1. Is memory sufficient?
2. Is HDD sufficient?
3. If it's not enough please suggest me
4. How long will it full sync?

Answer (score 0):

I ran 64GB RAM, 32 core, 400 GB SSD machine and it took about a week to sync. I think syncing full history is a problem that is being looked into or addressed differently by new proposed projects. Can't think of the name of one right now but you might want to do additional research.

Answer (score 0):

I think its impossible to not give a subjective answer to this question as it depends so heavily on what chain you are connecting to, how much usage that chain gets, and in exactly which we the chain is used.

The memory might be more than sufficient on a private chain with little expected usage, for example, but 32GB of RAM is not goign to be enough for the EOS mainnet in the long term.

As for the hard disk space, again if you want to run the EOS mainnet and keep a full history this is already in the region of I believe 50TB at the time of writing (beginning of 2021), and it is important for syncing that your hard drives be as fast as is possible as this tends to be the bottle neck when it comes to syncing a node. So an SSD is a minimum requirement.